How to remove duplicate rows in postgresql
I want to delete the duplicate rows from a table nashvillehousing. But when I try to use a CTE and delete the duplicate rows it isnt working and I get "relation cte doesnot exist",SQL state: 42P01.  I am using postgresql for this project,which I am doing following #Alex The Analyst. How can I remove the duplicate rows in postgresql. this is a screenshot of the code I am writing and the error that I am getting,{this is the error message I am getting} (https://i.sstatic.net/0NUOJeCY.png)
I tried using uniqueid as an identifier for duplicate rows then using EXCEPT and DELETE statements to delete the duplicate rows some of the rows were deleted but I am not sure If this is the correct solution or not.
Below is the code I used.
This code selects uniqueids.
SELECT uniqueid
FROM nashvillehousing1
EXCEPT(SELECT max(uniqueid)
FROM nashvillehousing1
GROUP BY propertyaddress)
I used the code below to delete the rows appearing more than once..
DELETE FROM nashvillehousing1
WHERE uniqueid IN (SELECT uniqueid
FROM nashvillehousing1
EXCEPT (SELECT max(uniqueid)
FROM nashvillehousing1
GROUP BY propertyaddress))
This code works but I am not sure If this is the correct way to identify duplicate rows and remove them.
Please help.

Please review [ask] and [mre]. Don't post images or links to images for elements that are inherently textual (e.g., code and error messages). Research the question prior to asking: this question has been asked and answered many times (e.g., 29409184.

This question is similar to: Delete duplicate rows from table with no unique key. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can use CTE and a Window function like this:
WITH duplicates AS (
SELECT
    uniqueid ,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyaddress ORDER BY ctid) AS rn
FROM
    nashvillehousing1 
 )
DELETE FROM nashvillehousing1 
WHERE uniqueid IN (
SELECT uniqueid 
FROM duplicates
WHERE rn > 1
);

The window function give a row number for each duplicated row, and the DELETE statement removes only the duplicated (row number > 1)
